# How to put a string of numbers seperated by whitespaces to an array?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a code that gets a string of numbers that is separated by whitespace like:
`"19 210 67"`

And separates them and prints them out. But the thing is I want to put three them into an array one by one
so I have an array of strings like: `["19","210","67"]`

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Heres my C++ code:

```
    std::string s = myText;
    std::string delimiter = " ";

    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = s.substr(0, pos);
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Comment: I don't see any array in your code sample.  Needless to say, you don't need all of this code to separate a whitespaced string of numbers.

Comment: how do you get myText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try boost split (found in #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
), here is an example with tab delimiters:

```
    string input("hello world"); 
    vector<string> result; 
    boost::split(result, input, ' ');
```

Alternative just declare a vector and push_back the tokens in the for loop of your code?

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse the string, and `std::vector<std::string>` to store each individual string:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "19 210 67";
    std::istringstream strm(test);
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string s;

    // loop for each string and add to the vector
    while ( strm >> s )
       vec.push_back(s);

    // Output the results
    for (auto& v : vec)
      std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
19 210 67
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you have an arbitrary number of values, and they all  `int`
First, you tokenize your string:

[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

the result of tokenization is a sequence of (`std::string` or null-terminated `char*` string) tokens, which you need to transform. This will look something like:

```
std::transform(
    token_iterator_at_first_token,
    token_iterator_after_last_token,
    [](const auto& token) { return std::stoi(token); }
);
```

... depending on how your iterators look. If you got a container, the iterators will probably be refered to as `the_container.cbegin()` and `the_container.cend()`.